# In AngularJs set controller action in routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I want to call a particular action of a controller in route Provider.How do I do that?

my code :

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/',
{

    templateUrl: '/items/angular_view',
    controller : 'myController.actionName'

})
});

app.controller('myController',function ($scope, $http,$routeParams) {


 $scope.actionName= function(page){


}
});
```

What is the correct way to do this?Can any one please guide me towards the right direction?Thanks.

Comment: for what you need to do that ? you can call service method in $routeProvider resolve method ? it will help to you or not ? for example `resolve: {
 isAvailable: ['$route', 'RegistrationService', function ($route, RegistrationService) {
                            return  RegistrationService.verifyEmail($route.current.params.token);
                        }]
                    },`

Comment: You really shouldn't. A controller is meant to be a controller of a particular element. What you want is `service`